# is there a way to get the value [product_code]1INSAZE from querystring and use it to run sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to get data from a querystring that looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/controller/php?ids[]=[product_code]1INSAZE
```

if I do :

```
$ids = $request->query->get('ids', null);

and dump it I get something like this :

array:1 [▼ 0 => "[product_code]1INSAZE" ] ]
```

if I `dump($ids[0])` I get:

```
"[product_code]1INSAZE"
```

i Need that string in order to do this:

```
$ids = $ids[0];

$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('k')

->andWhere("k.product_code = $ids")

->getQuery()

->getResult();

return $result;
```

I get this error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 72: Error: Expected Literal, got '['
```

is it related to that [product_code]? and If yes how do I get rid of that and execute the query?

Comment: You need `[product_code]1INSAZE` whole?

Comment: yes It needs to be in the query string, but it gives a syntax error when I run the code.

Comment: I got around the problem with the str_replace() php method, I removed the word.

Comment: That's because you're missing quotes around the value, e.g. `->andWhere("k.product_code = '$ids'")`, but better idea is to bind those parameters as answered by @UrsolSolutions.

Comment: Rikudou_Sennin thanks that's the solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

Don't just put the variable in quotes, it's unsafe and not the preferred way to use the QueryBuilder. Use parameters.

```
andWhere("k.product_code = :ids");
->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

If that doesn't work try escaping the '[' with '\['

EDIT: Used the wrong framework syntax

Comment: Expected Literal, got '\'

Comment: Did you add the parameters? Leave out the \ until you've tried that.

Comment: to the query string you mean? yes I did it give that mistake

Comment: I got around the problem with the str_replace() php method, I removed the word.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a solution though. Could you post the code that fixed the issue here?

Comment: I put ->andWhere("k.product_code = '$ids'") in my code as suggested by Rikudou_Sennin and it works, I suppose that was the problem.

Comment: It might fix the problem, but it's still not the actual correct way to do it.
If someone accesses your URL and edits the GET parameters like this:
ids[]="; DROP TABLE Users".
You just lost all your users.
This can be expanded to automatically look up the names of your tables and do so for your entire database. Or they can look up all the e-mail adresses of your users, or their social security numbers, if you store that.
This code should never be used on a live environment.